# How do you fake a .xhr request using fetch() and vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am working on stripping all of the jQuery out of a website and replacing it with plain JS. First off I have no control over the backend.  I can not change anything server side.
So the api will run my request through this:

```
def render_created_comment(comment)
    if request.xhr?
      render :partial => "comments/postedreply", :layout => false,
        :content_type => "text/html", :locals => { :comment => comment }
    else
      redirect_to comment.path
    end
  end
```

This is setup so the site can process normal js requests and those who refuse to use JS and treat the site like it is 1999.

So I need to write a fetch request that fakes being an .xhr , is that possible? I can already send the form data but I end up with the redirect which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: What is `request.xhr`? What even is that server-side language?

Comment: That is Ruby, and a .xhr is a jQuery ajax request.

Comment: Ah, [`Request.xhr`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/xhr?). And no, it has nothing to do with jQuery specifically, [the docs are quite clear](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/xml_http_request?) what it does check for. You can easily do the same with `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fetch()` add the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header. This is essentially what jQuery and other frameworks do.

```
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
}
```